# looking for javascript reference that's in master page

Tags: javascript, master-page

An old version of jquery is being loaded into my masterpage and I can't figure out where it's coming from.

Looking at the masterpage, I see

```
SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" language="javascript" Defer="true" runat="server"
```

When the page is loaded it has a series of other scripts and one points to an invalid location, the one being in question is..........

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/siteassets/jquery-1.7.min.js"></' + 'script>');
```

I've checked every solution and custom solution I've written and all are good.  Obviously it was added at some point.... now how to find out where and get it out?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it in a test/dev environment?

Comment: It's singular to this environment unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If it gets loaded, it means it's there. So if you can't find it on the site itself, start looking through the layouts folder.

As you can see on the picture below within the markings, this shows you where the file is loaded from.

All javascript files located in the `_layouts` folder will be loaded on the page.

As you can see in the red marking, there are 2 js files located in the 1030 language folder being loaded, and in the orange you can see all the js files located in the `_layouts` directly being loaded.

If there were other js files being loaded onto the page, their paths would be displayed in this box. Open your site in IE > press F12 > Go to "Script" tab > Click on dropdown to the left of the "Start debugging" button. It should display all javascript files being loaded and where they are located.

[image: Javascript load location]

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm trying to find out how that reference is getting added to the masterpage.  It's not in a page layout or on the masterpage directly, so it must be a CustomAction that's adding a scriptlink.  Where are scriptlinks loaded from?  I'm sure it's from an old sandbox solution that's been removed, but I can't find it.

Comment: They are usually loaded from layouts folder (1033 subfolder, if it's a site using the english language package). e.g. /_layouts/1033/<js file>

Comment: @CeeMoney Review my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like one of your web parts has registered a script dependecy.  One way to test this is to create a new page based on the Blank Web Part Page layout and then check to see if the script is being loaded.  If not, then it is a webpart.  If it is still being loaded, then check your page layouts, master page and any feature that makes use of delegate controls.

Comment: It's not the master page or any page layouts, and I've checked every custom feature that I've built or have source for.  I'm scratching my head.

Comment: Does the script get included when you create a new blank web part page and load that?

Comment: Just checked... yes it's included.

Comment: You also might want to look for the include in any custom .ASCX files that are in your CONTROLTEMPLATES folder below your 14 hive.  If one is there, it might point you to the feature where it is being included

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in PowerShell:

```
dir 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14' -Recurse |  
Select-String -Pattern "jquery-1.7.min.js" -SimpleMatch -List |  
Select Filename
```

It should return the name of any file containing that string in SharePointRoot

Comment: Only reference was logs.

Comment: I'd try looking at the entries in one of the log files to see if it gives a hint. Otherwise try running against c:\windows\assembly

Comment: Logs just say that the file can't be found.  No hits on the C:\windows\assembly search

Answer (score 0):

If this is a publishing site, you might also consider checking your Page Layouts, and not just your Master Pages.

Comment: I have double-checked those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any custom actions being used to load some [ScriptLink](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2010/03/01/scriptsrc-referencing-javascript-files-with-sharepoint-2010-custom-actions.aspx)?

You can also check if there is any delegate control (along with their Sequence nos) loading the Javascript

Comment: How can I find that out?

Comment: Check if there exists any custom Feature which is creating a custom action to load ScriptLink? Check Cisual Studio solutions.

Comment: Also, use IE Developer tools to delete the browser cache, or try using IE private browsing.

Comment: I've checked all of the custom features/solutions that are loaded and can't find anything, that's what's baffling.

Comment: Is there a specific page layout that is loading it or a master page?

Comment: Nope, I've check to make sure.  It's specific to one site collection.  I'm pretty sure it's a Custom Action but I don't know how to delete it.  It's not in any project I can find.

Comment: Can you find any custom feature for this custom action? A custom actions is provisioned using Elements.xml. Can you please also try fiddler and Mozilla Firebug to isolate the problem?

Comment: Tried both fiddler and Firebug (and Chrome dev tools).  I realize it's loaded via an elements.xml file, but I've checked every sandbox solution and farm feature that are deployed and can't find anything.

Comment: Are there any WFEs? Perform an IISreset across all WFEs.

Comment: Already tried that long ago unfortunately.

Comment: did you manage to find any custom action?

Comment: Nope, I haven't been able to find anything.